# selecting contact from autocomplete textview

Tags: android, autocomplete, contacts

i want to select the contact using autocomplete textview for sending sms. I have almost achieved what i want, but for one minute problem as you can see in the image. How can i solve that?

**activity_contact_with_auto.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/mmWhoNo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="To...." >
</AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**custcontview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#A5000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ccontName"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#A5000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ccontType"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/ccontNo"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#A5000000" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

```
public class ContactWithAuto extends Activity {

private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mPeopleList;
private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;
private AutoCompleteTextView mTxtPhoneNo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_with_auto);
    mPeopleList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    PopulatePeopleList();
    mTxtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.mmWhoNo);
    mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mPeopleList, R.layout.custcontview,
            new String[] { "Name", "Phone", "Type" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.ccontName, R.id.ccontNo, R.id.ccontType });
    mTxtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

public void PopulatePeopleList() {
    mPeopleList.clear();
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (people.moveToNext()) {
        String contactName = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String contactId = people.getString(people
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        String hasPhone = people
                .getString(people
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

        if ((Integer.parseInt(hasPhone) > 0)){
            // You know have the number so now query it like this
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,
            null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()){
                //store numbers and display a dialog letting the user select which.
                String phoneNumber = phones.getString(
                phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                String numberType = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                Map<String, String> NamePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
                NamePhoneType.put("Name", contactName);
                NamePhoneType.put("Phone", phoneNumber);
                if(numberType.equals("0"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Work");
                    else
                    if(numberType.equals("1"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Home");
                    else if(numberType.equals("2"))
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type",  "Mobile");
                    else
                    NamePhoneType.put("Type", "Other");
                    //Then add this map to the list.
                    mPeopleList.add(NamePhoneType);
            }
            phones.close();
        }
    }
    people.close();
    startManagingCursor(people);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg){
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);
    Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String value=(String)map.get(key);
        mTxtPhoneNo.setText(value);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_contact_with_auto, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

**Image**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: By the way `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add a onItemClickListener for the AutoCompleteTextView instead of having it as a seperate function.

```
 mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View arg1, int index,
                long arg3) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);

            String name  = map.get("Name");
            String number = map.get("Phone");
            mTxtPhoneNo.setText(""+name+"<"+number+">");

        }



    });
```

or implement OnItemClickListener for your activity and set

```
mTxtPhoneNo.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar to the OP, but there's one of of code that I'm not sure of. Would the activity_contact_with_auto.xml in his R.layout and R.menu be the same? Thanks!

Comment: @Regnarg No those two files cannot be the same.If you just want to test autocomplete textview, you can comment onCreateOptionsMenu method

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So onCreateOptionsMenu has nothing to do with the autocomplete textview then?

Comment: Can you modify it to work with `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: By the way `startManagingCursor()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The output you currently have seems to be the standard output of HashMap.toString method. So, you should  make your own implementation of HashMap and override toString method.

Comment: thats what i have done here, see this 
`public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int index, long arg){
    Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) av.getItemAtPosition(index);
    Iterator<String> myVeryOwnIterator = map.keySet().iterator();
    while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
        String value=(String)map.get(key);
        mTxtPhoneNo.setText(value);
    }
}
`

Comment: Yes, and this helps you to show items in the drop down list. But when you tap some entry seems that text in the TextEdit is filled by simply using item.toString.

Comment: define your hash map:
`class ContactMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
@override
public String toString() {
return <name> + <phone>;
}
}`

Then inside PopulatePeopleList:
`NamePhoneType = new ContactMap();`

And finally delete your onItemClick it should be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

With an AutoCompeleteTextView its can be useful just to do as what @user936414 said, but it can makes problem if you have biggest app, even more with an multiAutoCompeleteTextView so it s recommended to overide toString methode by creating a "custom" HashMap like that :

```
public class ContactMap extends HashMap<String, String> {

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.util.AbstractMap#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return "{}";
    }

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(size() * 28);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
        Object key = entry.getKey();

        if (key == "Name") {
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            buffer.append(value);
        } else {
            if (key == "Phone")
                buffer.append("<");
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value != this) {
                buffer.append(value);
            } else {
                buffer.append("(this Map)");
            }
            if (key == "Phone")
                buffer.append(">");

        }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}

}
```

and use it like this

```
                    // Using our custom HashMap
                    ContactMap NamePhoneType = new ContactMap();
```