# how to select multiple contacts in autocomplet textview?

Tags: android, autocomplete, contacts

I am new to android development. Now i am working in a app that is sending sms multiple contacts in my mobile.for that i am using `AutoCompleteTextView` with reference [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400504/selecting-contact-from-autocomplete-textview).
But by using this i am able to select one contact at a time. 
But i want to select multiple contacts. Can any body suggest me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May This Help you:

Buddy Use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` instead of `AutoCompleteTextView`

For Reference: [Click Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: buddy search for examples of `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in google it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

try multiAutoCompleteTextView. I think it will help you.

Comment: try this http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/example-of-multiautocompletetextview.html

Answer (score 0):

use check box to select multiple contacts. Store that contacts in array, then on button click use for loop to send sms form first index to last index of the array.

```
int cntChoice = myList.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = myList.getCheckedItemPositions();
for(int i = 0; i < checkedItemsCount; i++){             
    int position = checkedItems.keyAt(i);
    boolean isChecked = checkedItems.valueAt(i);    
    if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true){
         checked += myList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
    }
    selectedNos[i] = checked;
 }
```

use this selectedNos array to send sms.