# An autocomplete textview for contact names that get their numbers when clicked?

Tags: java, android, textview, contacts, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to learn how to make an autocomplete textview in an android app would have a dropdown list of contacts with their numbers, based on the letters that the user enters that match a part of a name of a contact.

How would I accomplish this? I've spend hours on google without finding a complete solution, which I thought was odd.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

A beginner android developer

MORE DETAILS: I wish to have a textbox similar to the recipient box for the default messaging app, where I would be able to start typing the name of a contact, and suggestions of contact names with their numbers would appear, which I would be able to click and fill my textbox with the number of that contact that I clicked.

Comment: I have found my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400504/selecting-contact-from-autocomplete-textview?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look [here](http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2013/07/simple-autocompletetextview-example.html) that should give you a good idea of how you can start to build up one on your own. For the contact list you will probably want to look at googles api about there sqllite database as well [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).